# Process going to wait_blocked state for 500 msec. How to find out for which resource it is waiting

Tags: c++, linux

Calling fopen to read 70Kb file, process scheduling out 500 msec, 1/10 reproducability. Analysed through ltt tracing, process going to wait_blocked state..How to find out for which resource it is going to wait state??

Comment: Attach a debugger to it?

Comment: its a performance issue, cannot attach a debugger to it,

Comment: Why not? Start it, attach a debugger 400ms later. In one out of the aforementioned ten cases it's blocked and you can find where by inspecting the backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cat /proc/$PID/wchan 
will give you the name of the kernel wait queue the process is blocked on

Comment: Sorry if my question is wrong, but how to call this line cat /proc/$PID/wchan in a real time, Means after fopen should i call this using system call. please guide.